# Cannot execute Docker Commands in UNIX environment

Tags: docker, unix, docker-machine

I installed the [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) installation to my UNIX (macOS), once I execute simple commands like,

```
$ docker run ubuntu
```

it shows following error prompted in terminal:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory.
```

I tried in several docker commands, but **`docker daemon`** throws the mentioned error message.

Comment: That is weird, docker will normally look for /var/run/docker.sock. Can you reinstall docker in your macOS?

Comment: i resolved this problem by reset option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is issue of Docker Engine startup not linked with docker demons, I resolved this problem by `Reset to Factory Settings` option in Docker Troubleshooting pane

Comment: Can you provide instructions how you did this?